# scala package conflict

Tags: scala

I have a library which has root package "scala", and now I have a project using this library, and I have a sub package named "com.zjffdu.scala". And the class file in this package needs to import classes from the library. So I have the following import statement.

```
import scala._
```

But because this class is also in package "scala", the scala compiler will look for files in current directory rather than the library.

So how can I explicit to tell scala to import classes from the library.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this:

```
import _root_.scala._
```

As you can see it's not very pretty — the best option is probably to avoid naming one of your packages `scala`.

And by the way — the root `scala` package is always preimported (though subpackages, of course, are not).

Comment: I wish I could award bonus points for not only answering the question, but *gently* advising how to avoid the problem in the first place without coming across as a condescending jerk.  +1