# Scala: Package import conflicts

Tags: java, scala

I'm importing an implicit: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global, and before this, I `import global.Analytics.xyzMethod`, where global is a directory in my package. However, for some reason, scala things this global is same as the first global. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
import _root_.global.Analytics.xyzMethod
```

see also: 
[scala package conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275289/scala-package-conflict?rq=1)

edit: I'm unfortunately unable to address the concern of som-snytt properly. Please take his comment into account.

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong or incomplete. If `global` is a subpackage of the current package: `imported 'global' is permanently hidden by definition of package global in package maqicode`.

Comment: @som-snytt: hmm,.. you raise an interesting point. Unfortunately I'm unable to modify my answer to reflect this properly, so I will delete this answer. (..and I find that I cannot, as the answer is already accepted)

Answer (score 13):

Use import rename :

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.{global => newName}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I should have noted I know this (and also because this is the simpler answer) :) Thanks again, I've upvoted both, but would be accepting the other as answer...