# How can I make scala's ammonite use scala.util instead of ammonite.util as default for util?

Tags: ammonite

In the "official" scala REPL I can do

```
scala> import util.Random
scala> util.Random.nextInt
res0: Int => -306696783
```

but in Ammonite-REPL I get

```
@ import util.Random
cmd3.sc:1: object Random is not a member of pack ammonite.util
import util.Random
       ^
Compilation Failed
```

So right now I have to use the `scala.` prefix to make it work in Ammonite:

```
@ import scala.util.Random
@ scala.util.Random.nextInt
res1: Int = 503117434
```

I'm kind of new to Scala so I don't get why would ammonite use a different `util` than the (for me) "official" `util`, so I would appreciate if anyone can provide a rationale for this.

And more specifically, Is there any way to make `util` to be `scala.util` instead of `ammonite.util`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that Ammonite is replacing a different `util` library for the normal Scala one, it's that the Ammonite namespace has it's own `util` package which has a whole bunch of methods specific to Ammonite. Perhaps it would be nicer if the developer had chosen a different name for his package, but this is not an issue specific to Ammonite. It is something you will run into all the time. When there is a clash of namespaces, your only option is to fully qualify the package name for the one you want. So what you actually did is a fine solution. You can find more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198778/scala-package-import-conflicts).

And btw, since there is no util.Random in the Ammonite package you can do this after your import--I tested and this is a cut and paste from my terminal:

`@ Random.nextInt 
res1: Int = 1045964363`

When you do actually have a collision of method names, you can find a solution [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-rename-members-import-scala-classes-methods-functions)